# Jquery - Testimonial fadeIn/out pagination

Tags: jquery, html, css, pagination

I got the pagination to scroll through the list but now I am stuck at making the pages scroll upon clicking the corresponding page.

I want to make it so that if I click on page 2, it should show me the second div, and so on..

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/njLyaddc/1/

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#page1").css("background", "#ccc");
    setInterval(function(){     
        $('#testimonials .slide').filter(':visible').fadeOut(1000,function(){
            if($(this).next('.slide').size()){
                $(this).next().fadeIn(1000);                
            }
            else{
                $('#testimonials .slide').eq(0).fadeIn(1000);
            }
            for(var i=1;i<$('.slide').length+1;i++){            
                if($('#testimonial'+i).is(":visible")){
                    $("#page"+i).css("background", "#ccc");
                }else{
                    $("#page"+i).css("background", "transparent");
                }               
            }
        });     
    },1000);  
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="testimonials">
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="aboutus_given_feedback" id="testimonial1">
            <div class="aboutus_bubble">
                1
            </div>      
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="slide" style="display:none">
        <div class="aboutus_given_feedback" id="testimonial2">
            <div class="aboutus_bubble">
                2
            </div>      
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="slide" style="display:none">
        <div class="aboutus_given_feedback" id="testimonial3">
            <div class="aboutus_bubble">
                3
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="testimonial_page">
        <span id="page1" class="pagination"></span>
        <span id="page2" class="pagination"></span>
        <span id="page3" class="pagination"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".pagination").click(function(){        
    $("#testimonials .slide").hide();
    $("#testimonials .slide").eq($(this).prevAll("span").length).fadeIn(500);
    $(".pagination").css("background", "transparent");
    $(this).css("background", "#ccc");
});
```

To make it work increase your `Interval` to 5 seconds. I've updated your fiddle.